# Get the image id from image cropper property

Tags: json, json.net, umbraco7

I am trying to get an image ID of the *Umbraco's Image Cropper* property in order to use it with `TypedMedia(id).GetResponsiveCropUrl()` method.

I am struggling to extract only the ID. My current implementation `item.GetProperty("mainImage").Value.ToString()` returns JSON object consisting of additional Image Cropper data such as focal point:

```
{ "focalPoint": { "left": 0.71111111111111114, "top": 0.57 }, "src": "/media/1004/9910_03_7326-river-flood_web.jpg", "crops": [ { "alias": "Carousel", "width": 700, "height": 400 } ] }1156
```

What would be the best approach for retrieving the image ID?

This is my implementation:

```
 foreach (Node item in Node.GetCurrent().GetDescendantNodes())
 {
    if (item.GetProperty<bool>("showInNewsCarousel") == true)
    {
        Response.Write(item.GetProperty("mainImage").Value.ToString());
    //    var slideImage = Umbraco.Media(item.GetProperty("mainImage").Value);
        <img class="img-responsive" src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(1155).GetResponsiveCropUrl("Carousel")" />
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `1156` at the end of the JSON?  Is that the image ID you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The `1156` value that you said in the comments was the image ID is not actually part of the JSON, but appears to have been tacked on later.  (If you try to validate the string at [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/), you'll see what I mean.)  Since the ID is not part of the JSON, you will not be able to use a JSON parser to get the value.  I think your best bet is just to find the last closing brace and then take everything after that.

```
string id = json.Substring(json.LastIndexOf('}') + 1).Trim();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was actually  thinking to get the substring but dropped this idea as there must be a better way to get the id property in Umbraco.